# How to make a new variable with binary parameters from existing data

Tags: stata

I am attempting to clean some data by making a do-file.
I've made an example of my data being the first column, with many of the data points being different amounts. I would like to then categorise them into a new binary dataset.

I understand the gen() to make a new variable, but I don't understand how to make a whole new data column with two variables based off of the "Income" category which would make the intended "bracket" category.

I was wondering how this would be done, and any Stata resources you may have found helpful when cleaning/analysing data.

| Income | Bracket |
| --- | --- |
| 100,000 | Above 99,999 |
| 27,000 | Below 99,999 |
| 143,000 | Above 99,999 |
| 60,000 | Below 99,999 |

Comment: `gen bracket = income >= 100000 if income < .` will create a variable with value 1 if `income` is 100000 or greater, 0 if less, but missing if missing. Modify according to taste. Your example leaves open what to do if income is 99999.

Comment: Thank you very much! The actual parameters are strings like "59999-69999" so hopefully that shouldn't be an option and I can just include all of the variables under 100,000 in the equation you have provided.

Comment: Your terminology is hard to follow: you appear to mean _values_ when you say _variables_ and I don't know what you mean by _parameters_ here.  If your `Income` is a string variable, you need quite different syntax and indeed should please show us a data example using Stata code (see very detailed advice in Stata tag wiki) and not a schematic example.